# MVC Email Confirmation (Sequence contains more than one element)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently trying to add email confirmation to my website and i'm experiencing a few problems.

I can succesfully register an account, upon registration the confirmationToken gets placed in my database and a email gets send with the query string link: http://www.example.com/RegistrationConfirmation?9ZPwZZrO-UmdpVpxXWjmRw when going to this link the controller action RegistrationConfirmation gets called and the method ConfirmAccount does a query to see if we can find a user with the confirmation token that was passed in the url.

When debugging I get the error "Sequence contains more than one element" on this line: `Account user = context.Accounts.SingleOrDefault(u => u.ConfirmationToken == confirmationToken);`

I'm not sure what's going wrong cause the token is unique and there are no duplicate tokens in the database.

Register HttpPost:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        string confirmationToken = CreateToken();
        Account account = new Account(model.Username, model.Password, model.FirstName, model.LastName, model.Email, false, confirmationToken);
        if (DatabaseHandler.isUsernameDuplicate(account.Username))
        {
            // is duplicate // provide notification
        }
        else
        {
            Session["accountID"] = Repository.InsertAccount(new Account(model.Username, model.Password, model.FirstName, model.LastName, model.Email,false, confirmationToken));

            // Email Logic
            try
            {
                await client.SendMailAsync(message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Problem sending email: " + e.Message);
            }
            return View("ConfirmEmail");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

RegistrationConfirmation HttpGet:

```
[HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult RegisterConfirmation(string Id)
    {
        if (ConfirmAccount(Id))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ConfirmationSuccess");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("ConfirmationFailure");
    }
```

ConfirmAccount method:

```
private bool ConfirmAccount(string confirmationToken)
    {
        RecipeDbContext context = new RecipeDbContext();
        Account user = context.Accounts.SingleOrDefault(u => u.ConfirmationToken == confirmationToken);
        if (user != null)
        {
            user.IsConfirmed = true;
            DbSet<Account> dbSet = context.Set<Account>();
            dbSet.Attach(user);
            context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove SingleorDefault() and check the result.. you will get to know its not duplicate and if you want to avoid this error then use FirstorDefault().

Comment: Checked the result and it's not duplicate, if I use FirstOrDefault instead of SingleOrDefault it passes the query and sets IsConfirmed to true but for the wrong user

Comment: I dont know about your database but be logical.. if it is giving a user to matched by the confirmation token and if that user is wrong then its your mistake.. there is no error in code. The question was about Sequence contains more than element not about your confirmation token process

Comment: And post me the result of context.Accounts.where(u => u.ConfirmationToken == confirmationToken).ToList();

Comment: ToList returns 0 accounts

Comment: How can it be possible that FirstorDefault() returning you result and ToList() is not returning anything.. crazyy..

Answer (score 0):

Turned out nothing was wrong with the query itself, the RegisterConfirmation HttpGet did not seem to get the confirmToken value so I added "Id = Request.QueryString.ToString();" and everything is working perfect now :)